# Straight line with arrows and dots

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am beginner for Ti*k*Z package and I'd like to know how to draw following graph in LaTeX.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Please read the [introductory material](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) for this site. When you post a question, please provide a ["Minimal Working Example" (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that starts with `\documentclass`, includes all relevant `\usepackage` commands, ends with `\end{document}` and compiles without errors, even if it does not produce your desired output.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A quick solution

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill (0,0) circle (1pt) node[below] {$n$} (2,0) circle (1pt) node[below] {$n+1$} (-2,0) circle (1pt) node[below] {$n-1$};
\draw[-latex] (0,0)--(-1,0) node[above] {$n$};
\draw[-latex] (0,0)--(1,0) node[above] {$a(n)$};
\draw (-3,0)--(3,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much @JouleV ! That is enough for now, I could modify it. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 5):

an alternative:

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations.markings, positioning, quotes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance =22mm,
->-/.style = {decoration={markings,
              mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow{>}}},postaction={decorate}},
dot/.style = {circle, fill, inner sep=2pt, node contents={}}
                        ]
\node (d1) [dot,label=below:$n-1$];
\node (d2) [dot,label=below:$n$, right=of d1];
\node (d3) [dot,label=below:$n+1$, right=of d2];
\path   (d2) edge [->-, "$n$" ']    (d1)
        (d2) edge [->-, "$a(n)$"]   (d3);
\draw   (d1.west) -- + (-1,0)
        (d3.east) -- + ( 1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]